# I can't send mail with Php

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send mail with php on my website. I don't know very well php.After I search and I created mail.php files. It's includes this code:

> ```
> $name    = $_POST[“your-name”];
> $from   = $_POST[“your-email”];
> $message = $_POST[“your-message”];
>
> $headers = "From: $mail\r\n"."Content-Type: text/html;Charset=iso-8859-9-r\n ";
> mail("admin@ardazaman.com","konu / Subject ", $message ,$headers);
>
> ?>
> ```

When I send to mail, The output is that:

[image]

I won't know what I do. Thank you for helping. Have a good day :).

Comment: That's a message from your email client. Either fix that, or don't send HTML.

Answer (score 1):

That's on your email client provider, they don't allow sending html emails.

Best you can do is to contact them to see if there are any workarounds. otherwise you'll have to send a plain email.